# 301 Redirect rule to cover multple cases

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Is there any way I can do all the following ( and similar ) redirects with a rule

```
Redirect 301 brand/brand1 http://domain.com/department/brand1
Redirect 301 brand/brand2 http://domain.com/department/brand2
Redirect 301 brand/brand3 http://domain.com/department/brand3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `RedirectMatch` that gives your regex capabilities like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 brand/([^/]+) http://domain.com/department/$1
```